# Java audiofile in a loop. Not as an Applet.

Tags: java, loops

I am absolutly new to Java.
But I would like to make my Girlfriend a little gift written in Java.
The Programm itself I have and it works...but what I would like to add, is an Audiofile that loops itself as long as the Programm is running. 
I ve looked through a lot of Stuff, tried many things and somehow it seems I am making a mistake. And yes I know there are many code Examples.
It is not an Applet.

That is the following Code...It should not be cleancode, I just hope I get it to work somehow.
If someone could help I would appreciate it.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Shore
 */
public class audio {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException  {
            File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Shore\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Meli13\\src\\WW.wav");

            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(audioInputStream);
            AudioFormat af = audioInputStream.getFormat();
            int size = (int) (af.getFrameSize() * audioInputStream.getFrameLength());
            byte[] audio = new byte[size];
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, af, size);
            bufferedInputStream.read(audio, 0, size);
            Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip.open(af, audio, 0, size);
            clip.start();

            }
}
```

Thanks a lot.
the WW.wav is in the same folder.

Comment: Do you have any error or output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How cute! Is this like cupid.stackoverflow.com? ;)

Since you're absolutely new to Java, keep in mind that the API docs can be pretty useful for understanding what a particular class does. In this case, you're interested on the Clip class, whose documents can be accessed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html).

As the document states, you can set the class up such that it loops the playback automatically. You'd go around doing that like this:

```
        ...
        Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(af, audio, 0, size);
        clip.loop(3); //Added this line
        clip.setLoopPoints(0, -1); //Added this line
        clip.start();
        ...
```

`clip.loop(3)` tells Java to repeat the clip 3 times. If you want to repeat forever, use `Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY` as the parameter. `clip.setLoopPoints(0,-1)` tells java to repeat it from its very beginning (0) to its very end (specified by -1). These are frame numbers, not absolute time. So if you wanted to loop through specific parts of the file, you'd have to figure out the math for that. But that's kinda of topic.

Finally (and most importantly), `Clip` starts a new thread. That means that if your application terminates right after calling `clip.start()`, the `Clip` thread will be terminated and you won't really hear anything because it will be terminated too quickly.

I'm not sure how your application is setup, but in the code snippet you provided, the only way to actually hear something is pausing the main thread while the `Clip` thread is running. You can do that as follows:

```
while (clip.isRunning()) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

I hope that helps and you score points with the lady. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Clip was the right Direction and with your advice I managed it somehow. I runes now as a Thread with the GUI Applikation.

Comment: @FlorindeRidder No worries. If my answered helped you to solve the problem, please mark it as the answer and vote it up if you think it's suitable. Good luck with the lady ;) Cheers

Comment: Done, I can t vote it up though...I need 15 Reputation, sorry, I don t posses that...yet